# Not able to get the Datepicker object from onClick method of a button in the same activity

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Hi I am getting a NPE

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3100)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14304)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3095)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rkapps.calendarsharing.SyncToCloudActivity.getDateFromDatePicket(SyncToCloudActivity.java:59)
    at com.rkapps.calendarsharing.SyncToCloudActivity.syncWithCloud(SyncToCloudActivity.java:47)
```

from the below code

```
package com.rkapps.calendarsharing;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import com.rkapps.calendarsharing.events.Synchronizer;

public class SyncToCloudActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync_to_cloud);
        DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        DatePicker endDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
        setNormnalCalendar(startDatePicker);
        setNormnalCalendar(endDatePicker);
    }

    private void setNormnalCalendar(DatePicker startDatePicker) {
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
              try {
                Method m = startDatePicker.getClass().getMethod("setCalendarViewShown", boolean.class);
                m.invoke(startDatePicker, false);
              }
              catch (Exception e) {} // eat exception in our case
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sync_to_cloud, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void syncWithCloud(View view) {
        DatePicker startDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        Date startDate = getDateFromDatePicket(startDatePicker);
        DatePicker endDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);
        Date endDate = getDateFromDatePicket(endDatePicker);
        new Synchronizer(getContentResolver(), this).syncToCloud(startDate ,endDate);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param datePicker
     * @return a java.util.Date
     */
    public static java.util.Date getDateFromDatePicket(DatePicker datePicker) {
        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

}
```

The NPE is coming from the line in which I am trying to access my date picker from the syncWithCloud()- which is called when a button in the same activity is pressed method.

I read from android froums  that I am supposed to use this DatePicker using a DialogFragmnet. but since I want my app to be supported for android 2.3 , and dont want to gte involved with the versioning complications of supoprt libraries I chose not to use the Dialog fragments, is there anyway I can use the Datepickers ? Thanks in advance .

the activity xml is as shown

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_date" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_date" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sync_to_cloud" 
        android:onClick="syncWithCloud"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since your onCreate seems to find the DatePickers fine, why not hold a reference to them inside your Activity and use that reference in the syncWithCloud method instead of trying to find them again inside the view.

Comment: Thanks  brianestey I solved the issue by suing findByviewId() instead of view.findByViewId() I am not sure what is the exact difference.

Comment: Ahh - good catch!  The View that is passed into the onClick is the actual Button that was clicked, not the LinearLayout of the entire xml.

Comment: thanks  brianestey :)